# Mocking an Entity Framework model?

Tags: entity-framework, testing, linq-to-entities, mocking

Is it possible to mock an EF model so that I can test code which uses the model classes without getting rid of LINQ to Entities code strewn throughout my project? Or will it be necessary to set up a test database for the model to hit instead?

Comment: See my answer for the question [Mock Entity Framework database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087857/mock-entity-framework-database/14406546#14406546). A mock object context can be created from your entity model using a T4 template. This is the way the regular POCO classes are created, and it can be extended pretty easily to create a mock object context and interface to make it swappable with your concrete object context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your LINQ code in [Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object). The DAOs would have separate interface and implementation code. Your test code would mock the DAOs.

If you don't want to do that, you'll need a test DB.

Comment: Since I'm not a hardcore TDD type, this sounds overly complicated just to test some systems I'm currently working on. Shame EF wasn't designed to be easily testable!

Comment: EF v2 will not suffer from these complications.  We'll be able to do unit testing against POCO objects and lose less hair.

Comment: Even when creating another layer, how would you perform save operation - as EF uses mMamDbEntities.SaveChanges(); after Entity reference has been chnaged