# Mocking Entity Framework Context

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, mocking

I'm using the entity framework to access my database and I want to mock the database context inside my unit tests so that I can test my middle tier classes free of their dependency on real data. I know that I'm not the first to ask about this [(Mocking an Entity Framework Model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604191/mocking-an-entity-framework-model), but after some googling I have an instinct that it might be possible to instantiate the context based on the model's metadata alone.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Even when creating another layer, how would you perform save operation - as EF uses mMamDbEntities.SaveChanges(); after Entity reference has been chnaged

Comment: See my answer for the question [Mock Entity Framework database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087857/mock-entity-framework-database/14406546#14406546). A mock object context can be created from your entity model using a T4 template. This is the way the regular POCO classes are created, and it can be extended pretty easily to create a mock object context and interface to make it swappable with your concrete object context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with just metadata, there's a good article on it, and unit testing EF in general, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/diego/archive/2008/03/03/unit-testing-your-entity-framework-domain-classes.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

A well known way of doing this is to use the [Repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). This acts as a layer over your concrete data access implementation and provides a place to inject test doubles.

Comment: Even with the repository pattern (which is definately a good idea) you may still want to keep an ObjectContext around to take advantage of it.

Comment: The repository patterns I've seen for EF use the ObjectContext internally.

Comment: The ObjectContext should usually injected into repositories as a dependency - Repository and Unit of Work are orthogonal.

Comment: Even when creating another layer, how would you perform `save` operation - as EF uses                 mMamDbEntities.SaveChanges(); after Entity reference has been changed

Comment: Entity framework is a repository, why would you use a repository to implement a repository?