# Artificially create a connection timeout error in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ado.net, adomd.net

I am using asp.net MVC framework and using EntityFramework to connect to database. Sometimes while connecting to database I get timeout error. These errors are very rare.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:
 An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. 
See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to 
completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

---

```
var myList = new List<MyConnection>();
using (var db = new MyDb())
            {
                var activeConns = db.Connections
                                    .Where(c => c.Key == tKey)
                                    .Where(c => c.IsActive)
                                    .ToList();
                if (activeConns.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Some custom logic
         myList.add(conn);
                }

            return myList;
        }
```

**I am not setting any connection timeout period. Is there any best practice when working with Entity Framework?**

**How can I generate this kind of defect artificially so I can test our software?**

Answer (score 0):

The way we've handled this sort of thing in our code base is to use [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) - allowing us to swap out the real implementation (for example, database) with a fake implementation used only for testing.

From the client's perspective, the fake one behaves the same, but we have more control over the behaviour for testing things like errors (throw a timeout error on 5th request for example).

[Mocking Entity Framework Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710383/mocking-entity-framework-context) is another SO question that goes into a bit more detail on how to set this up, specifically for EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use Reflection to throw SQL Timeout Exception.
Check this article for help :
http://blog.developers.ba/post/2009/03/08/SqlException-class-doesnt-have-public-constructor.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to throw a SQL exception. What I want to achieve is while creating SQL connection or executing SQL command, I want system to generate Connection or Command Timeout messages.