# How to write Moq unit test for Attach() with Entityframework 6

Tags: mocking, entity-framework-6, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

To UPDATE a record, I have used method Attach() like

```
            var entity = new Movie() { ID = 1};
            var dbEntity = DbContext.Movies.Attach(entity);
            dbEntity.Genre = "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr";
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

How to write unit test for the function above? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking Entity Framework Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710383/mocking-entity-framework-context)

Comment: It sounds like you're writing unit tests for Entity Framework, not your own code.  Why do you feel you need to write a unit test for the `Attach` method?

Comment: I am trying to make sure the record is updated properly.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to do integration testing.  In that case, you don't want to moq anything related to Entity Framework.  You'll need to set up your unit test to point to a clean database, run your code and then use some standard ADO code to query the database and see if the update worked.  But if you don't trust Entity Framework to do its job, why are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two contexts for your tests. The first is for creating mockData, the second for running service which you want to test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).